# Heatmap from large CSV file

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib, plot, heatmap

I'm trying to plot a heatmap from a large CSV. Specifically I have a matrix like this:

```
O0 X1 X2 X3 . . . Xn
Y1 Z1 Z2 Z3 . . . Zn
Y2 Z1 Z2 Z3 . . . Zn
Y3 Z1 Z2 Z3 . . . Zn
.  .  .  .  . . . .
.  .  .  .  . . . .
.  .  .  .  . . . .
Yn Z1 Z2 Z3 . . . Zn
```

With more than 4K X values, and 15K Y values, the Z values are between 0 a 1000, and I need to generate and image where 0 values are a cold blue pixel, and 1000 values are a heat red value, with a degraded in the rest of values, I tried with some python utilities but all of them say that the fata is too large, someone have a library to plot that huge amount of data?

There is the code I'm using to substract the data:

```
reader = csv.reader(open('../Data/160627_185815_1_OK.csv', 'rt'), delimiter=';')
reader2 = csv.reader(open('../Data/160627_195553_1_OK.csv', 'rt'), delimiter=';')
first = True
valuesGT1 = 0
print(reader)
Z = []
for row in reader:
    row2 = next(reader2)
    row2.pop(0)
    row.pop(0)
    if not first:
        C = [float(a) - float(b) for a, b in zip(row, row2)]
        with open('results_test.csv', 'a') as csvfile:
            spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',',
                                    quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
            spamwriter.writerow(C)
            csvfile.close()
        Z.append(C)
    else:
        first = False;
```

Thanks in advance.

Edit: [Example CSV](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/a0e19fb1a1151a95b0cd3dea8f75954a/TESTCSV100x100.csv)

Comment: Woah, so you're gonna generate a 4000px x 15000px image?

Comment: Could you provide a csv as an example (maybe just a 100*100 extract), so we can have real data to work with ?

Comment: @Cyrbil Hi, there is a extract from a file: [link](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/a0e19fb1a1151a95b0cd3dea8f75954a/TESTCSV100x100.csv) Thanks.

Comment: @SeanFrancisN.Ballais That's the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your problem using [vips](http://www.vips.ecs.soton.ac.uk/index.php?title=VIPS). Here's my program:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

import gi
gi.require_version('Vips', '8.0')
from gi.repository import Vips

im = Vips.Image.new_from_file(sys.argv[1])
im = (255 * im / 1000).falsecolour()
im.write_to_file(sys.argv[2])
```

I ran it like this on my laptop against some test data I made:

```
$ wc x.csv
    14990 122873030 362045970 x.csv
$ time ./heatmap.py x.csv x.tif

real    0m36.415s
user    0m37.508s
sys 0m0.904s  
$ ls -l x.tif 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 john john 184333196 Jul 14 10:01 x.tif
$ vipsheader x.tif 
x.tif: 4099x14990 uchar, 3 bands, srgb, tiffload
```

So it makes a 200MB tif file in just over 35 seconds. Memory use peaks at about 30MB of RAM, though it will use a temporary file as well.

You don't give your platform, but you can install on OS X with `brew install vips`, or on linux via your package manager. It's a little harder on Windows.

Edit: I see your file is the difference between two other CSV files. You could do the whole thing in vips, something like:

```
a = Vips.Image.new_from_file(sys.argv[1])
b = Vips.Image.new_from_file(sys.argv[2])
heatmap = (255 * (a - b) / 1000).falsecolour()
heatmap.write_to_file(sys.argv[3])
```

Comment: Thanks, that make it easy.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I got so far:

```
import csv
from PIL import Image

with open('TESTCSV100x100.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')

    i, j = 0, 0
    pixels = dict()
    for i, row in enumerate(reader):
        for j, val in enumerate(row):
            r, g, b = (int(int(val) / (1000 / 255)),
                       int(20 - int(val) / (1000 / 20)),
                       int(255 - int(val) / (1000 / 255)))
            pixels[i, j] = (r, g, b)

img = Image.new('RGB', (i + 1, j + 1), "black")
data = img.load()
for k, v in pixels.items():
    data.__setitem__(k, v)

img.save('/tmp/test.jpg', "JPEG")
```

Obviously for your very large dataset, this won't be efficient. Here is some possibility:

- Using numpy: It can read a csv very fast and it allows to pass the result to PIL easily with `Image.fromarray()`
- Use multiprocessing: With a pool of workers, you can send lines to be processed to different threads